# Can projects be transferred to another account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dns

I have set up a series of zones in one project under cloud dns. I would like to transfer this project, with the zones, to another account.

Any ideas about how to do this? Seems that projects, should be able to be transferred to another account within a Google apps for work domain should a person leave the company or be transferred to a different department and someone else needs to take over for them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to transfer ownership of a project to another Google account in three steps.

Step 1: Add the other account's email address as an owner on the project. Instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cloud-console#_addingmember).

Step 2: Since it's not possible to transfer ownership of the billing account associated, have the new owner create a new billing account and associate it to the project. Instructions [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6110821?hl=en).

Step 3: Remove the previous owner from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered importing the zone records, from this project into a BIND or YAML format and exporting back in your new project.

Refer how to import/export recordsets from your zones
https://cloud.google.com/dns/records/